# Can I annotate an ObjC method to tell the static analyzer its argument is non-nil if it returns YES?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

The code I'm working with has a utility function like

```objectivec
@implementation Utils
+ (BOOL)isNullOrEmpty:(nullable NSString *)string {
  return (string.count > 0);
}
@end
```

So obviously `+isNullOrEmpty:` only returns `YES` if `string` is non-nil, but Xcode's static analyzer doesn't know this. Is there a way to tell the analyzer that whenever this method returns true, its argument is guaranteed to be non-nil?

I thought I saw a macro that did something like this in a WWDC video a few years back, but I don't remember what it was and I haven't found anything useful googling for it.

Comment: What happens, if you explicitly check for 'nil' instead of taking advantage of the message-to.nil behaviour? (Yes, I know …)

Comment: I think if it will be macro, static analyzer will know that argument is not nil. Something like `#define isNullOrEmpty(arg) (nil == (arg) || 0 == (arg).count)`